# Tabbed Boxes - loading content individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Using a simple jQuery CSS tabbed-menu content box, how could I load each content area upon clicking that tab. Rather then everything loading as soon as you go to the URL. I'd like the page to load quickly, and the content to load individually upon accessing it - to optimize my site for speed.

Comment: Do you have any code down ? You could quite easily bind the ajax to a click event .

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery-UI library? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AJAX so that when the tab is selected, the content is loaded from an external source. Make sure you use some sort of loading indicator image so that the user knows the page is not broken.